# Sequence Number vs Self-implementation

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence

I have a `Customer` table which can have about 1M records. There is also an `Order` table which has `OrderCode` field will be generated by the pattern `{CustomerId}_{Date}_{IncrementalNumber}` (The `IncrementalNumber` will be reset per day for each customer and can have gap). I am considering the solution for `IncrementalNumber`:

1. Use the `Sequence Number` supported in database (Sequence number will be generated for each customer).
2. Create a new table called `SequenceCustomer` which contains `CustomerId` and `NextValue` property.

I wonder which is the better way between those approaches ? Somehow I prefer the 1st solution but it may create too much sequences in database and I'm not sure if it can affect performance.

Comment: Do you mind gaps in the incremental number?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, No, gaps is ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use only a single sequence for all tables, and I would store that in a `bigint` column. The desired `OrderCode` can be calculated when you query the table, or you could use a view that calculates it.